# HttpListenerResponse 404 and Firefox not interpreting it

Tags: internet-explorer, c#-4.0, firefox

I got an issuee with Firefox. I implementet a Webservice using HttpListener.
Working great, the only Problem I encountered now is, that firefox doesnt seem to interpret my 404 correctly.

All I do with the HttpResponse Object is setting StatusCode to 404 and closing it.
Nothing else.

Internetexplorer correctly displays the standard 404 page, Firefox displays an empty one, or if the url ends with xml for example, it gives an XML-Parsing error.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the Code which doesnt do much really, but that might be the Problem, I don't know.

```
void handlePageNotFound(HttpListenerResponse response)
{
    response.StatusCode = 404;
    response.Close();
}
```

I Installed an addin for firefox to check if the statuscode is received correctly. It is.

Comment: I have the same problem. Browser shows nothing instead of 404 page. It is especially gets worse when user requests image files. Image file is tried to be shown and invalid file message is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Generally web servers keep separate html files to show when a page is not found, like 404.html. So, other than sending this message I think Mozilla waits web server to provide appropriate content instead of showing a default page.

So I added extra lines to response.StatusCode = 404

```
try
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    string str = "<center>404 - Page not found</center>";
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);                    
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)((e is FileNotFoundException || e is DirectoryNotFoundException) ? HttpStatusCode.NotFound : HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    context.Response.StatusDescription = e.Message;
}
catch
{
    Logger.LogError("Exception processing request 'ProcessFileRequest' - Catch block: {0}", e);
}
```

A better way might be having 404.html file and providing its content for such cases.